# How to use an excel document as a username and password database for a html login page

Tags: javascript, html, excel, phpexcel

Hello I have a personal project, I have created a login page that allows me to login and works I am trying to find a way to link an excel document to the page and use that to store the username and password (plain text at the moment)

**HTML**

```
<form id="login-form">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address></label>
            <input type="email" name="username" id="username-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password-field" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login-form-submit">
        </form>
        <div id="login-error-msg-holder">
            <p id="login-error-msg">Invalid username and/or password</p>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login-form-submit");
const loginErrorMsg = document.getElementById("login-error-msg");
loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = loginForm.username.value;
    const password = loginForm.password.value;
    if (username === "admin@admin.com" && password === "admin") {
        alert("You have successfully logged in.");
        window.location.href('index.html');
    } else {
        loginErrorMsg.style.opacity = 1;
    }
})
```

Thank you

Comment: This way of authentication is not the best idea. I understand that it's a personal project and authentication may not be the focus of what you're trying to do. But perhaps in the future look into services like Firebase Authentication or Passport JS

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/) Request and Excel Online APIs. Really, this is a bad idea overall for security and client-developer trust, but if you are doing it, that's the best (and perhaps only) method. Make sure your file is on [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com) and is *not* shared.

Comment: Is this what you needed to know?

Comment: Yes thank you Can you link me a tutorial if you do not mind

Comment: Sorry. I don't have the resources. Just create a new, secure Exchange account, and go to flow.microsoft.com. Set everything up using the Request trigger for secure access and have it called by your web server. Don't give out the link or use it in client-side operations. Keep that section of your server secured with a Unicode 64-character password.